# Cash On Delivery Based On Zipcode Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9

Following is the observer.php file for an extension that restricts Cash On Delivery Payment Method Based On Pincode On The Checkout Page.

This extension works perfectly fine with the built in Cash On Delivery Payment Method in Magento.

My issue is that, when a customer on my website goes to the checkout page to complete his order, the cash on delivery payment method is not visible initially. Only when the customer enters his Zip Code, and if that particular zip code is available for COD, the COD payment method appears. If that zipcode is not eligible, the COD option continues to be invisible.

I want the COD option to be visible initially when the zip code has not been entered and after the customer enters the zip code and if that zip code is not available, a message should be displayed saying that COD is not available.

I know this particular code needs to be altered a bit to achieve that. Kindly help me out if possible.

Observer.php

```
class Mfp_Cod_Model_Observer {

    public function getCashOnDelvery(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $event           = $observer->getEvent();
        $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
        $result          = $event->getResult();
        $isModuleEnable = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/enable');

        if ($isModuleEnable) {
            if ($method->getCode() == 'msp_cashondelivery' ) {
                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                $add = $quote->getShippingAddress();
                $postcode = $add->getData('postcode');

                $comparisonMode = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/mode');
                $zipCodes = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/zipcode');
                $isExist = false;

                if (trim($zipCodes) == '') {
                    $result->isAvailable = true;
                } else {
                    if(strpos($zipCodes, $postcode) !==  false) {
                        $isExist = true;
                    }

                    if ($isExist != true) {
                        $zipCodesArray = explode(',', nl2br($zipCodes));
                        if (count($elementLineArray) > 1) {
                            foreach ($zipCodesArray as $codzipLine) {
                                $elementLineArray = explode('-', $codzipLine);
                                if (count($elementLineArray) == 2 && ( $postcode >= $elementLineArray[0] && $postcode <= $elementLineArray[1] )) {
                                    $isExist = true;
                                    break;
                                } else if($postcode == $codzipLine) {
                                    $isExist = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $returnValue = '';
                    $returnValue = ($isExist)?true:false;

                    $result->isAvailable = $returnValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check if zipcode is not added like :

after

```
$postcode = $add->getData('postcode');
```

add

```
if(!isset($postcode) || empty($postcode)) {
    return true;
}
```

In order to get shipping address of checkout page use

```
$address = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()
                              ->getShippingAddress();
```

in $address object you will get complete information of shipping address including postcode.